# intents not defined for discord bot

Tags: discord

first it said Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') so then i added intents.FLAGS.flagname and now its saying intents is not defined

my full log before adding intents.FLAGS.flagname:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aviai\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:13:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

after adding intents.FLAGS.flagname:

```
ReferenceError: intents is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aviai\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

my index.js looks fine and i dont know if i should add intents.FLAGS.flagname or do something else or if thats causing the problem, how can i solve both?

```
    require("dotenv").config();


const {REST} = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { Player } = require("discord-player");
const fs = require("node:fs");
const path = require("node:path");
intents.FLAGS.flagname;

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]
});

// Load all the commands
const commands = [];
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.joint(_dirname, "commands");
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles)
{
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command  = require(filePath);

    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    command.push(command.data.ToJSON);
}

client.player = new Player(client, {
    ytdlOptions: {
        quality: "highestaudio",
        highWaterMark: 1 << 25
    }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
const guild_ids = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);

const rest = new REST({version: "9"}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);
for(const guildId of guild_ids)
{
    rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, guildId), {
        body: commands
    })
    .then(() => console.log(`Added commands to ${guildId}`))
    .catch(console.error);
}

});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if(!command) return;

    try
    {
        await command.execute({client, interaction});
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
        await interaction.reply("An error occured while executing that command.");
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem can be solved fairly easy. I can recommend using an intents calculator like [this one](https://discord-intents-calculator.vercel.app).

After you let it calculate the intents you can just do a simple creation of the client like this:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: 'your calculated intents'});
```

That also means you can simplify your import like this:

```
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
```

Also the line `intents.FLAGS.flagname;` is not needed.

I hope that already solves your Problem.